# php word filter function?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, loops

I have programmed this function

```
function bad_words($val){
    global $pre; 
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM " . $pre . "BAD_WORDS") or die(mysql_error());
    $rs = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql); 
    if (mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0) { 
        $bad_words = $rs['BAD_WORD']; 
        $replace = $rs['REPLACE']; 
    } 
    $val = str_ireplace($bad_words, $replace, $val);
    return $val; 
}
```

---

`BAD_WORDS Table (ID, BAD_WORD, REPLACE)`

---

When I use this function it replaces word with id = 1 but doesn't replace the other words.

What am I missing?

Comment: [In case you want some feedback on the idea of profanity filters.](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/10/obscenity-filters-bad-idea-or-incredibly-intercoursing-bad-idea.html)

Comment: what is in the `$pre` variable?

Comment: I also consider `global` a bad word. `mysql_*` as well btw.

Comment: how do you call this function within your code?

Comment: @Ibu - It's probably just a table prefix for namespacing - likely doesn't play into the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are fetching only the first row from the table. You have to use a loop to iterate through
all the rows in the result set.

```
function bad_words($val)
{
global $pre;
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM " . $pre . "BAD_WORDS") or die(mysql_error());

if (mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0) {
   while($rs = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
      $bad_words[] = $rs['BAD_WORD'];
      $replace[] = $rs['REPLACE'];
   }
}
$val = str_ireplace($bad_words, $replace, $val);
return $val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, that is because you are not looping through the resulting rows, you are only executing code on the first one. Once you determine there is one or more rows (`if (mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0)`), You'll need to loop through the records one at a time and perform the action.

check this for more: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php